# If you unlock you don't have to unlock again in X time

Tags: settings, lock-screens

Is there a way to have my phone stay unlocked for some period of time after I have unlocked it once (via PIN, pattern or whatever). In other words, if I unlock my device with my PIN, if I turn the screen back on within the next 30 minutes I wouldn't have to re-enter my PIN.

If it matters my device is on Android 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

I use an app called [Delayed Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.delayedlock2.trial). You can set it to stay unlocked for a set time after last unlock or after screen off and then it will enable the pin/pw again. It can also be used to unlock the device on specific wifi networks and lock when it disconnects (you still have to use your pin/pw the first time). And there is a plugin for it that uses location to disable the pin/pw as well.